# How to avoid namespace content indentation in vim?

Tags: c++, vim, indentation, auto-indent

How to set vim to not indent namespace content in C++?

```
namespace < identifier >
{
    < statement_list > // Unwanted indentation
}
```

Surprisingly, ['cinoptions'](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'cinoptions') doesn't provide a way to edit namespace content indentation.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Not sure when it was introduced but my installed version of vim, v7.3.353 has a cino option that handles cpp namespace explicitly. I am currently using the example value:

`cino=N-s`

and as per `:help cinoptions-values`

```
NN    Indent inside C++ namespace N characters extra compared to a
  normal block.  (default 0).

cino=                      cino=N-s 
  namespace {                namespace {
      void function();       void function();
  }                          }

  namespace my               namespace my
  {                          {
      void function();       void function();
  }                          }
```

The link the OP posted is for v7.3.162

Comment: I was using v7.2 of vim and it really didn't have that option (I had double checked it at that time and I have just 'triple checked' it now). I'm getting v7.3 now. Thanks!

Comment: Is it equivalent to `cino=N0`?

Comment: It's not same, there's option in :h cino and then /namespace.
personally I use cino=(s,j1,N-s so I can open my...
function ( and have indent with this open on multiple lines )

Answer (score 11):

[cpp.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2636) will solve your problem, but if you don't want the full-blown Google coding style then just take a peek at the plugin source and see how it handles namespaces. It's super simple:

```
function! IndentNamespace()
  let l:cline_num = line('.')
  let l:pline_num = prevnonblank(l:cline_num - 1)
  let l:pline = getline(l:pline_num)
  let l:retv = cindent('.')
  while l:pline =~# '\(^\s*{\s*\|^\s*//\|^\s*/\*\|\*/\s*$\)'
    let l:pline_num = prevnonblank(l:pline_num - 1)
    let l:pline = getline(l:pline_num)
  endwhile
  if l:pline =~# '^\s*namespace.*'
    let l:retv = 0
  endif
  return l:retv
endfunction

setlocal indentexpr=IndentNamespace()
```

In essence all you do is match the last non-blank line against `/^\s*namespace/`, and if it matches return 0 (as the indent position for `indentexpr`); otherwise return Vim's builtin cindent mechanism's value.

I essentially stole the code from the plugin, stripped anything that isn't namespace-related and renamed the indent function to `IndentNamespace()`. Save this as ~/.vim/indent/cpp.vim.

Comment: Since I place the opening curly bracket at the line below the namespace declaration this code doesn't work. It finds { at the previous non-blank line. Still, it is a great solution.

Comment: Ah, you're right. I think I trimmed too much form the plugin. :s Try again now. The fix will ignore any comments or scope braces after the namespace line.

Comment: I'm sorry taking so long to answer. Just tried your new solution but it still didn't work. The "full-blown" Google coding style script you suggested also didn't work. I don't know why yet.

Answer (score 2):

As many have mentioned Google C++ style is quite good.
I 'd recommend to install `clang-format` which I find it better than the recommended plugins, and then install a vim plugin on top.

## Install clang-format

#### Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install clang-format
// or for older versions:
sudo apt-get install clang-format-3.6
```

#### Mac:

```
brew install clang-format
```

## Vim plugin:

[rhysd/vim-clang-format](https://github.com/rhysd/vim-clang-format)

Install using your favorite plugin manager.
Checkout the plugin's link for more options. The default style is `google`, but there is also `llvm` and others.

One option you might need if you are using a custom version of the command is for

example:

```
let g:clang_format#command ="clang-format-3.6"
```

Answer (score 1):

I use [cpp.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2636) which is inspired by the Google C++ Style Guide. Among other things, that script does what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I've configured vim to not indent for the namespace. These are the relevant lines in my vimrc:

```
autocmd Filetype cpp set shiftwidth=2
set cino=>2(0^-2g0h2
```

Frankly, I don't remember how to interpet the `cino` statement, but `:help cinoptions` should help in deciphering it. One caveat: I think it's configured to not indent when using a format like so:

```
namespace foo 
{ // <- curly bracket on next line
...
```

versus

```
namespace foo { // <- same line
```

Since I put the curly bracket on the next line exclusively for namespaces, it does what I want, but it might not work if you use that style for other function declarations, for, etc.

Comment: Like I said, 'cinoptions' (long for 'cino'), inherently, won't make it. From the lines you have pasted, '^-2' combined with 'shiftwidth=2' removes the indentation of namespace contents, but it also removes the indentation of every block with an opening curly brace at column 0.

Comment: Yes, that's the case. The cpp.vim solution looks better and I'm incorporating in my vim config just now :)