# Skip indentation of first line after JUnit @Test annotation

Tags: vim, junit

In general I prefer to have annotation tags for methods, including @Test ones, on the line before the method declaration like this

```
@Test
public void testMyMethod() {
// Code
}
```

rather than

```
@Test public void testMyMethod() {
// Code
}
```

I have java specific settings in ~/.vim/ftplugins/java.vim. What can I add to java.vim such that indentation is skipped at the first line after the @Test tag? At the moment vim will, as it is supposed to according to java.vim, indent 4 characters giving

```
@Test
____* <-- cursor placed here
```

while I would prefer

```
@Test
* <-- Cursor placed here
```

Comment: Perhaps it's not something you need to add to java.vim but something you need to remove.  I have no specific settings relating to java in my vim and your example works as you want for me.  One thing you could check is `set cinwords`.  If it contains an `@` and `smartindent` is on, this would cause the behaviour you are experiencing.

Comment: If not yet solved, could you post a link to your .vimrc and the vim.java you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do something similar in C++, where my company's coding style doesn't want indents in namespace blocks.  There's an answer for that at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2549019), adapting it to your question would just swap the `'^\s*namespace.*'` bit to your desired pattern.  If it's for all annotations, perhaps simply...

```
function! IndentAnnotation()
  let l:cline_num = line('.')
  let l:pline_num = prevnonblank(l:cline_num - 1)
  let l:pline = getline(l:pline_num)
  let l:retv = cindent('.')
  while l:pline =~# '\(^\s*{\s*\|^\s*//\|^\s*/\*\|\*/\s*$\)'
    let l:pline_num = prevnonblank(l:pline_num - 1)
    let l:pline = getline(l:pline_num)
  endwhile
  if l:pline =~# '^\s*@.*'
    let l:retv = 0
  endif
  return l:retv
endfunction

setlocal indentexpr=IndentAnnotation()
```

Save this in your vimfiles (inside ~/vimfiles or on windows in your homedir or inside ProgramFiles\vim\vimfiles) as indent/java.vim.  You may be able to simplify by removing the while/endwhile hunt for a non-blank line if you require an annotation to occur on a line exactly above the line you're indenting (with no intervening blank lines).