# How to set vim not auto indent in extern "C" { line

Tags: vim

In our project, there will be

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
    int foobar();  // <-- vim auto indent it
```

how to set vimrc or c-support let vim not auto indent just for extern "C" beside use Marco to replace the extern "C" {？

Comment: I think the indent in vim is based on regex but not syntax, vim is not that smart.

Answer (score 1):

I found `extern "C" { //}` works for me.  Not sure if this depends on any specific
`cindent` or `cino` settings.

Answer (score 0):

The indents in vim configured via 'cinoptions'. But it doesn't support "extern C". See [answer on similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2549224/966897).

```
function! IndentNamespace()
    let l:cline_num = line('.')
    let l:pline_num = prevnonblank(l:cline_num - 1)
    let l:pline = getline(l:pline_num)
    let l:retv = cindent('.')
    while l:pline =~# '\(^\s*{\s*\|^\s*//\|^\s*/\*\|\*/\s*$\)'
        let l:pline_num = prevnonblank(l:pline_num - 1)
        let l:pline = getline(l:pline_num)
    endwhile
    if l:pline =~# '^\s*extern "C".*'
        let l:retv = 0
    endif
    return l:retv
endfunction

setlocal indentexpr=IndentNamespace()
```

Save this as ~/.vim/indent/cpp.vim

Comment: If this used to work, it doesn't work for me on Vim 8.1